# MATLAB Passing variable name into save function

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to use a variable name as the filename for a PDF output. The `save` function works but only when the filename is contained in `''`. So... `saveas(h, 'fname', 'pdf')` works, but I want the value of the variable `fname` as the filename, not just the text `'fname'`. I have tried it without the `''`, but that simply doesn't save anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Indeed in my case your example works fine (R2012b x64). Of course `fname` must be a string. If it is not you have to do `saveas(h,num2str(fname), 'pdf')`, i.e. convert the number in a string first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine on my machine (R2012b winx64) and generates the two expected pdfs

```
xx = 0:.01:1
h = plot(xx,sin(xx))

f_name = 'fname'  % // string version
saveas(h, f_name , 'pdf')  % // PDF1 - name: "fname.pdf"

f_name = 10;  % // now variable is a double
saveas(h, num2str(f_name) , 'pdf')  % // convert number in string first
                                    % // PDF2 - name "10.pdf"
```

Comment: Can the `'-append'` function also be used in conjunction with this, to add multiple plots to one file?

Comment: @MarkHughes; the right way is to make one plot, than do `hold on` or `hold all`, then plot all the other things you need and finally save. Google for `hold on`.